# I am trying to update user data with role using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to update user data with roles but unfortunately  i am getting error please help me how can i resovle this issue thanks.

i am getting error please chack

Illegal string offset 'name'

https://flareapp.io/share/Bm01YzaP

Note i am using spaite laravel permission

**return request**

```
{
"_token": "6uupkcqfyN8eqmnXTRztBXostJur03a8g3iTaRbC",
"_method": "put",
"name": "zubair",
"roles": [
"Employee"
],
"password": null,
"email": "zubair.m@horizontech.biz"
}
```

**controller**

```
    public function update(Request $request, $user)
    {
            return $request->all();
        $user['name'] = $request->name;


        if ($request->password) {
            $user['password'] = Hash::make($request->password);
        }
        $user['email'] = $request->email;
        $user->update($user);
        $user->syncRoles($request->roles);

        return redirect()->intended('user');
    }
```

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts. Why do you use unreachable code in your update controller?

Comment: In your function, the code after `return $request->all();` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller `update` method can be better written using [Laravel Route Resource Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding) as:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user->name = $request->name;
    if ($request->password) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    }
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->save();
    
    $user->syncRoles($request->roles);

    return redirect()->intended('user');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper route model binding update(Request $request, User $user)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have a // before your first return.. i cant have 2 returns on your function or all the code after the first return will not work.

After that you should declare your $user variable as a User Model like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user) {
      // your code
}
```